# Passing date variable dynamically to the URL in ADF

Tags: database, rest, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, aws-rest-api

**What I am trying to do:**

I am fetching data using REST API in ADF, and want to move the output file via Copy Activity to Blob storage.
I can successfully do that if I pass in the exact URL with date like this:

> "https://xf3txd72ja.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/prod/v2/all/01-12-2021/31-12-2021"

The dates in the URL mean the start date and end date. This date changes every month at source and reflects the past 1 month. For example, next months URL will have date like: 01-01-2022/31-1-2022

I want to build a mechanism in my pipeline (if I can) so that I don't have to manually go in and change the date in the URL.

**What I have tried so far**

I have tried passing Date function in source dataset and also tried passing the date variable.

**Date Variable**

```
@formatDateTime(addToTime(convertTimeZone(utcnow(),'UTC','New Zealand Standard Time'),-1,'Month'),'MMM yyyy')
```

**Date Function**
[image]

**Error**

[image]

**EDIT**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing format specifiers:

### Examples:

Date format: `@getPastTime(1,'Month','dd-MM-yyyy')`

[image]

Start of Month: `@startOfMonth(string(utcnow()),'dd-MM-yyyy')`

[image]

End of Month: `@addDays(startOfMonth(string(utcnow()),'o'),30,'dd-MM-yyyy')`

[image]

You can use multiple variables and then form a dynamic URL using variables without much confusion.

**WebActivity Configuration**

URL: `@Concat('https://xf3txd72ja.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/prod/v2/all/',variables('Start of Month'),'/',variables('End of Month'))`

[image]

Refer official MS docs for more details: [DateFunctions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#date-functions)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It helps but I'm not quite there yet. So by using StartOfMonth we get values for start of that current month. How do I get start and end of month values for previous month?

Comment: there is no direct function for that, you can try as I have used in example : add days of that month (30 or 31) to the  `Start of Month` value. For previous month, use combination of `getPastTime()` and `addDays()` functions

Comment: Start of Month: `@startOfMonth(string(getPastTime(1,'Month','o')),'dd-MM-yyyy')`

Comment: End of Month: `@addDays(startOfMonth(string(getPastTime(1,'Month','o')),'o'),30,'dd-MM-yyyy')`

Comment: Thank you! those queries work, but now I cant configure the URL with variables in the Copy Activity. I can Only do that in web activity, which will make the process of transferring the output file really complex. Is it possible to pass the URL in Copy activity somehow?

Comment: you can use the same URL expression as base url for REST source in COPY activity too

Comment: see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/parameterize-linked-services?tabs=data-factory

Comment: Thank you. Please check my EDIT. I will go through the doc.

Comment: Use linked service parameters to form URL dynamically and then pass value to these parameters by assigning already calculated variable with dates values in the pipeline.

Comment: Checkout this [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqIKW.gif) like `@{concat('https://api.instantwebtools.net/v1/',linkedService().newdate)}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241405/discussion-between-newbie-and-karthikbhyresh-mt).